# How to extract an array item from an array variable in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and now currently using Laravel version 5.2.

I have this set of array:

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": 'sample',
        "question_index": 1,
        "question": "Hope you could help me buddy.",
        "data": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "answer": 'yes',
                    }
                ]
    }
```

The array was created using the following eloquent query:

```
$exam_data = $this->template->where('id', $id)
                            ->with('data')
                            ->get();
```

Now I wanted to retrieve the 'data' array inside that array using Laravel 5.

I tried the following code but to no avail...

```
$user_data = $exam_data->data;

$user_data = $exam_data['data'];

$user_data = $exam_data->get('data');
```

Though I can pluck it using this:

```
$user_data = $exam_data->pluck('data');
```

which has this result (I don't know why but I'm not satisfied on it):

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "answer": 'yes',
        }
    ]
]
```

Is there any ways or method that I can use to retrieve the 'data' array?

Like For example:

```
$user_data = $exam_data->data;
```

and how about accessing 'answer' field?

```
$user_data = $exam_data->data->answer;
Is this possible?
```

Appreciate any comments or suggestions. thanks!

Comment: can you try $exam_data['data']?

Comment: @emuigai Yup I already did that. I also tried to convert it to JSON  and Array but still to no avail.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin precisely yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exam_data = $this->template->where('id', $id)
                            ->with('data')
                            ->get();
```

returns a `Collection` of m**ultiple records**, something like:

```
Collection [
  0 => Collection,
  1 => Collection,
]
```

That's why you can't access "data" directly from `$exam_data`, and that's what `->pluck()` does for you.

`pluck()` does the same as:

```
$filtered = [];
foreach ($exam_data as $exam) {
  $filtered[] = $exam->data;
}
```

if you `dd($filtered)` you get what you're after.

If you are expecting a single record, though, you could use `->first()` instead of `->get()`, which returns a **single** Collection and there you can access the data relationship with:

```
$exam_data = ..... ->first();
$data = $exam_data->data;
```

Comment: Well, it depends on the relationship, if is single or multiple (belongsTo or belongsToMany, for ex.). dump `$exam_data->data` and you'll see if it's a collection of multiple items or just one ;)

Comment: Wow a thorough explanation! I tried it and it works. The first() method saves the trouble.
Thanks mate. :)

Comment: I tried accessing the member and the first() method also applies. It's all about recursion after all. Now I understand everything needed for it. thanks much